# It cannot be done. I think

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

I have spent too much time on this question. I am convinced this cannot be done. Please prove me right (or wrong) and explain why.

> Below is a 5x5 grid. Digits 1 through 9 go in the 9 yellow boxes.
>   Every digit must be used. Yellow boxes can only contain a single
>   digit, nothing else.Obviously all 9 digits will have to be placed.
>
> Bluish boxes will have the givem Math operators. Only + - * / ^ and =
>   can be used. Nothing else.

[image]

Now can a grid be created where all vertical, horizontal and diagonal equations are correct? Direction of the equation not important.

I tried and tried and failed. The closest I came was
[image]

I got horizontals, diagonals and two of the 3 verticals to work but not the middle.

Can this be done given the restrictions? Why?

Which operators will make this possible, if any.

Please don't say "not equal to" :)

Comment: fun problem, but just wondering where it came from or if you are trying to make up a puzzle.

Comment: All my puzzle @tom. I have too much time at hand. BTW I am serious when I say it probably cannot be done.

Comment: Congrats on 20k reputation!

Comment: I did not find a solution by brute force permutation, but I did not finish proving it logically. For that, I began by trying each number in the centre, and then 9 can go in one of two locations, and I could not complete any arrangment. Sadly I gave up at 4, because presenting every attempt exhaustively isn't much fun ;) One point of interest is rot13(gurer jnf ab arrq gb purpx qvivfvba, orpnhfr vg vf pbirerq ol gur erirefr zhygvcyvpngvba).

Comment: You could place two plus signs there.

Comment: Instead of exponential I also tried `^` as `XOR` for a cheeky solution but none found.

Comment: Thanks @Rand al'Thor. Credit mostly goes to Grandpa :)

Comment: @WeatherVane `XOR` doesn't help, but introducing `logical OR` gives us 24 solutions.

Comment: If the direction of the equation is not important, should we be getting the absolute value of each number? Because in the example you gave, 9 - 8 = 1 is true, but 1 = 8 - 9 is false (-1). Also, 2 ^ 3 = 8 is true, but 8 != 3 ^ 2. This constraint alone makes this problem not feasible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Using only basic operators (+ - * / ^)

> It is not possible but there are many solutions that are missing a single row/column. 
>  This Python program would print all complete solutions if any existed: https://repl.it/repls/OrchidAcceptableNaturaldocs

There are [16 solutions](https://pastebin.com/DWD6JMdq) that, like yours, are missing the center column:

There are [**64 boards**](https://pastebin.com/dSAnwQhB) total that are missing *any* one row, column, or diagonal.

Here is the complete list: https://pastebin.com/dSAnwQhB

and here is the generating code: https://repl.it/repls/BriefWarmInstitutions

#### If we were to introduce bitwise operators

> There are [24 possible solutions](https://pastebin.com/FbKg64Sh), one of which being:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Generating code: https://repl.it/repls/AuthorizedCriminalPagerecognition
>
>
>  Including only `OR`: [8 boards](https://pastebin.com/kU0JUN5P)
>
>  Including `OR` and `AND`: [24 boards](https://pastebin.com/FbKg64Sh)

#### Including Square Root, Square, and Factorial operations

> There are [46 complete boards](https://pastebin.com/KbNRgSFr) that involve at least one of sqrt, square, and factorial
>
>  For example:
>
>  [image: 2]
>
>  Example with factorial:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Generating code: https://repl.it/repls/WhoppingIncompleteApplicationframework

Comment: Great effort. IF you allow certain operators within the number boxes like ! or Square or square root so you change the numbers themselves it could be possible, right?

Comment: @DEEM There definitely are solutions if you allow sqrt, square, and factorial (likely hundreds). I've found several and hope to have a complete list soon.

Comment: @DEEM [Here is an example](https://i.imgur.com/9jXfrTn.png)

Comment: That is great. So there is a Magic square with 1 to 9!!

Answer (score 3):

I used integer linear programming to verify that the problem is infeasible.  It turns out that there are 64 near misses with one violation like yours.  These reduce to 8 solutions up to symmetry:

> ```
>  143
>  752
>  896 
>  
>  143
>  792
>  658 
>  
>  165
>  739
>  824 
>  
>  176
>  832
>  954 
>  
>  263
>  459
>  817 
>  
>  263
>  781
>  594 
>  
>  263
>  945
>  718 
>  
>  263
>  954
>  817
> ```